# Calculate change of mouse movement in angle

Tags: c#, wpf, point, angle

In my C# application , i want to restrict the horizontal and vertical scrolling by computing the mouse movement angle difference.

Grater than 60 degree angle need to be tracked as vertical scroll.

I have the initial X,Y positions and current X, Y positions.How can i calculate the angle of mouse movement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard of sine and cosine? Check your maths-book...

Comment: Do you mean you want to know whether the user rotates the mouse while staying in the same spot? I'm afraid that's not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the angle in radians:

```
int dx = Math.Abs(x2 - x1);
int dy = Math.Abs(y2 - y1);

double angleRadians = Math.Atan2(dy, dx);

double angleDegrees = (angleRadians * 180)/Math.PI;
```

You will probably want to ignore angles for which `dx` or `dy` is less than a certain number (something like 16 would do it).